# how to make the animation controller transition in code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

like below, if I want to make a conditions "int" Equals to 1, how can I write it in code?

[image]

Comment: You mean like using [`Animator.CrossFade`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFade.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Animator anim;
    int jumpHash = Animator.StringToHash("Jump"); // Enter the parameter here
    int runStateHash = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Run"); // Enter the parameter here

    void Start ()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", move);

        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && stateInfo.nameHash == runStateHash)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger (jumpHash);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this still require the condition to be configured correctly using a Trigger ... I don't see how this would be an advantage against simply doing the same but with the Int condition ...